# Mongodb generating default random numbers in schema level is generating same numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb as database with mongoose as ORM. I have a field booking_id in my schema which is unique , so I cannot have it null. Thus I have designed my code something like this.

```
  var bookingSchema = new Schema({
    booking_id_customer: {
        type: Number,
        default : Math.floor(Math.random()*900000000300000000000) + 1000000000000000,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
```

It works perfectly for the first time, but from 2nd time onwards I get this duplicacy error.

```
    { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: xx.bookings.$booking_id_customer_1 dup key: { : 4.439605615108491e+20 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index:
```

I expect it to generate random numbers but I have no clue about whats going wrong in 2nd time.

Comment: May be monoose is not comparing your value because of `e`. Try with 10 digit `Math.floor(Math.random()*900000000300000000000 + 1000000000000000, 10)`

Comment: Why not just use `ObjectId()`? It will be unique every time you generate. And there is already an `_id` field with that in it. Why do you think you need "another' unique identifier?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are setting the default just once, at schema creation.

If you want it to be called for each new document, you need to turn it into a function that Mongoose will call:

```
default : function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*900000000300000000000) + 1000000000000000
}
```

However, there is another issue with your code: the values you're using (900000000300000000000 and 1000000000000000) exceed [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), which can lead to problems.

I would suggest using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` as id generator, which is also what Mongoose and MongoDB use to create (unique) document id's:

```
booking_id_customer : {
  type    : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  default : mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  index   : { unique: true }
}
```

Or re-use the `_id` property of the document, which is also unique.

Comment: I was trying to set default in two columns. One is using `uuid` and another is using `randomstring`. But it was creating a value once and then repeating the same value for the next DB records/documents. The solution worked for me too by binding those default into `function() { // uuid/randomstring logic }`

Comment: @amrendra make sure you're not using `default: uuid()` but `default: uuid`